# Laravel: How to write resource controller methods

Tags: laravel, controller, resources

I've written the following:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $image = Image::find($id);
    $path = $image-file_path;
    return response()->file();
}
```

In routes/web.php I have the following:

```
Route::resource('image', 'ImageController');
```

Now I don't know why when I go to `http://localhost:8000/image/5` in my browser, I get:

```
FatalErrorException in ImageController.php line 48:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Image' not found
in ImageController.php line 48
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here $path = $image-file_path;
This should be $image->file_path;

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a properly-namespaced path to "Image" on the line:

```
$image = Image::find($id);
```

And then fix in accordance with Kostas' suggestion so it's not breaking on the very next line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Could you please elaborate? I have trouble understanding what I need to do in your answer.

Comment: I'd suggest spending some time reading through http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php for a better understanding of why it's currently failing.

Comment: Ideally the namespace should not be a controller file. it should be a Model class not a controller class. May be `App\Image`, if you didn't create any folder for Models and you are generating models  by Laravel Cli.

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1 : Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Image' not found

You are missing to include your model "**Image**" in your controller

Include you model in top of the contoller:

For eg :

```
use App\Image;
```

Issue 1 : $path = $image-file_path;

```
Change form $path = $image-file_path;
```

to

```
$path = $image->file_path;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need include Image model in your controller

use App\Models\Image;

or if you don't have folder Models

use App\Image;